# What are the various methods of optimizing storage space used when we uses TARMK based repository

Tags: aem, tar

What is meant by TAR compaction in terms of an AEM repository supported by TARMK ( AEM 6.x) ? Also What is the difference between **online** TAR Compaction and **offline** TAR compaction and how can we perform the two?
Which one of the two is more suitable to which use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tar files as the storage tends to grow in size and starts claiming disk space every time when data is created or updated as data in tar files are never overwritten rather it keeps adding new versions. To mitigate the same, AEM has garbage collection mechanism which is known as ‘Tar Compaction’ to remove the unused data and reclaim the disk space.

As the name suggests the Online Revision Cleanup is done while the AEM instance is up and running where as the Offline Cleanup requires the AEM instance to be shut down. Online revision cleanup is present in AEM 6.2 under restricted support, Offline revision clean up is available with OAK run.

The steps for both are available in AEM documentation -

- Online revision cleanup [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform/storage-elements-in-aem-6.html#Performing%20Online%20Revision%20Cleanup)
- Offline revision cleanup [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform/storage-elements-in-aem-6.html#Performing%20Offline%20Revision%20Cleanup)

Advanced runmode/option for oak-run tool can found [here](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/tree/trunk/oak-run) on Github.

As to which is recommended, Offline compaction is to be preferred in most of the cases and Online to be used in case when AEM instance can not be brought offline for compaction.
Also the offline compaction is extensively supported as against the Online compaction which has limited support and available only in AEM 6.2

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you linked to AEM 6.1 Offline Revision Cleanup but to AEM 6.2 Online Revision Cleanup?